# teamcity rest api to replace the contents of build step for multiple projects

Tags: rest, api, build, configuration, teamcity

I want to know how can we update the contents of build step in multiple projects in teamcity.
For eg-
I have a common build step "prepare json file" in teamcity for 1000 projects and i want to update the content of this build step for all the projects at once with some other project specific values.
What could i do here?

Thanks
Abhishek Somani

Comment: Could u explain ur use case, as there might be better ways than REST API? Also, is this a hypothetical or an existing configuration?
In the former case, u can use a Build Configuration Template when creating ur build configurations.
Then u can manage the common setting of the builds that use the template in one place.
Alternatively, u can use DSL to describe ur configuration as code, which should be easier to manage and scale.
In the latter case, u can search the file system under <DataDir>/config/projects for .xml files containing the setting u need to change and change them with a script

Comment: i have around 1000 build configurations in teamcity across multiple projects and i want to change the contents of all at once. For eg- there is one build configuration with the name "prepare json file" and i want to replace the json content with other values for all the projects.

Comment: There is no quick and easy way doing that through REST API and it would involve scripting. You would need to iterate through the build configurations (/app/rest/buildTypes/). In each build configuration get the list of build steps (/app/rest/buildTypes/<config_ID>/steps). Then get the first step of the received steps by its ID and change the step. The first step in different configurations will have different ID so there is no easy way to access it without getting the list of steps first.